# ALTER DATABASE to change COLLATE not working

Tags: mysql, django, collate

I am using Django on Bluehost. I created a form for user generated input, but unicode  inputs from this form fails to be stored or displayed  of characters. So I did a SO and google search that I should change the Collate and Character set of my database. I run this sql

`ALTER DATABASE learncon_pywithyou CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

from `python27 manage.py dbshell`, which initiated a mysql shell, what shows on screen is 
`Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)`.

So I assume the problem is solved, but it is not actually. This sql has not done anything, as I later find it in phpMyAdmin provided by Bluehost. All the Varchar fields of all the tables are still in `lantin1_swedish_ci` collate.

So assume that `alter table` should work instead. I run this on mysql
`alter table mytable character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;`

although on screen it shows `Query OK. 4 rows affected`, it actually did nothing either, the collate of those fields in `mytable` did not change at all.

So I finally manually change the fields in phpMyAdmin for `mytable` and this works, now I am able to insert in this table with unicode and also they display correctly, but I have around 20 tables of such, I don't want to change them one by one manually.

Do we at all have a simple and effective way of changing Collate of each field to store and display correct unicodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to [**@StuartLC**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21354178/792290) ,
For Changing All 20 tables charset and collation use below query, Here world is database name

```
SELECT 
CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",TABLE_SCHEMA , ".",TABLE_NAME," CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci") AS AlterSQL
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "world";
```

The above will prepare all `ALTER` queries which you need to run.

Comment: Thanks for this experienced answer, now I believe those DBMS do have considered automation in design, even with not much keywords. This is what I want, it should save me a lot of time. And thanks for @StuartLC for the useful basis, "convert to".

Comment: Same note as below here: if nothing is converted in the table, the charset stays unchanged - you have to use the query without "convert to" in that case. MariaDB 10.0.27.

Answer (score 10):

Changing collation at the database level sets the default for new objects - existing collations will not be changed.

Similarly, at a table level, [only new columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-column.html) (<sub>See comment at the bottom</sub>) are affected with this:

```
alter table mytable character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

However, to convert the collation of existing columns, you need to add `convert to`:

```
alter table mytable convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Just dropping a note there: if nothing is converted in the table, the charset stays unchanged - you have to use the query without "convert to" in that case.

Comment: @korkman - This was the exact issue with our database we were trying to update. It's a bit silly that it won't update the collation if there is no conversion needed.

Comment: Thanks @korkman for information : we have the issue and we doesn't understand why! It's more than a bit silly in my opinion!!